# I have to press two times an item for delete it using setOnClickListener when i have only one item in the list

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code...the idea is that when the user push **imagedeletenumberlistview** component the element that the user has pressed is deleted. If I have multiple items it works fine, but when I have one item I have to double press the item for it to delete me.

```
numberViewModel.numbers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ listN->
        if (listN.isNotEmpty()){
            val adapter=PhonesAdapter(requireContext(),listN)
            binding.listPhones.adapter=adapter
            binding.listPhones.setOnItemClickListener { _, view, position, _ ->
                view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagedeletenumberlistview).setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Contact delete ${listN[position].contactName}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    numberViewModel.deletenumber(listN[position])
                }
            }
        }else{
            val adapter=PhonesAdapter(requireContext(),listN)
            binding.listPhones.adapter=adapter
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

PhonesAdapter class:

```
class PhonesAdapter (private var contex:Context, private val phones:List<NumberEntity>) : ArrayAdapter<NumberEntity> (contex,0,phones){

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_phones,parent,false)
    val phones=phones[position]
    v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contactName).text=phones.contactName
    v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.phoneNumber).text=phones.number
    return v
}
```

}*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have to create an interface listener in your `PhoneAdapter` and set `OnClickListener` for `imagedeletenumberlistview` in `getView` method like this:

```
class PhonesAdapter(private var context: Context, private val phones: List<NumberEntity>) :
    ArrayAdapter<NumberEntity>(contex, 0, phones) {

    private lateinit var mListener: ItemClicker

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_phones, parent, false)
        val phones = phones[position]

        v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contactName).text = phones.contactName
        v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.phoneNumber).text = phones.number

        v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagedeletenumberlistview).setOnClickListener {
            mListener.onDeleteClick(position)
        }

        return v
    }

    interface ItemClicker {
        fun onDeleteClick(position: Int)
    }

    fun setItemClickListener(itemClicker: ItemClicker) {
        mListener = itemClicker
    }
}
```

and then change your `Flow` observing method to this:

```
numberViewModel.numbers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { listN ->
    if (listN.isNotEmpty()) {

        val adapter = PhonesAdapter(requireContext(), listN)
        binding.listPhones.adapter = adapter

        adapter.setItemClickListener(object : PhonesAdapter.ItemClicker {
            override fun onDeleteClick(position: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Contact delete ${listN[position].contactName}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                numberViewModel.deletenumber(listN[position])
            }
        })
    } else {
        val adapter = PhonesAdapter(requireContext(), listN)
        binding.listPhones.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` if necessary.

Comment: I want that the item has been deleted when i Click a buttom that in my item_layout, and if i do like you said the item will be deleted if i click in anywhere

Comment: You can use an interface listener in your `PhoneAdapter`. If you provide me with it's code, I'll be able to help out more :)

Comment: Sorry. This is a secondary project, but anyway i add the code of my PhoneAdapter class. I will apreciate your help.

Comment: @devblock I have edited my comment. You can take a look! :)

Comment: It's works well but, Could you explain me a litter more why use an interface?